# Mypy: Not warning if return type is incorrect

Tags: python, mypy

I am not sure if it is a setup issue or mypy is corrupted in my machine. I have a below class,

```
class A:
   _b: B

   @property
   def b(self) -> C:
      return self._b
```

I expect mypy to complain incorrect return type but I get no errors found. Is this expected?

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=7f012eb595ce66f4f42abf31f5e2b140

Comment: Unless  `B` inherits from `C` mypy should indeed complain.

Comment: What mypy version are you using?